# How to make ABAP understand "_" as a special character in a global variable value from BODS?

Tags: abap, sap-data-services

I have one requirement in BODS to execute ABAP dataflows with dynamic global variables. The ABAP code is a custom one with dynamic `where` clause. I am trying to send the global variable value like `Field-name like "%underscroe%"`. But instead of fetching records with only 'underscore', it is fetching all records from the table.

Do you have any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ESCAPE` clause for this. If you wanna search for underscore, set

```
LIKE '%#_%' ESCAPE '#'.
```

I am not sure, if it works with BODS though.

Comment: Hello Suncatcher, The above code is working but I have another issue in ABAP that is if I am trying to send dynamic like clause Field-name like $variable. In the $variable I am sending '%#_%' ESCAPE '#' but it is not working, it's fetching all records. Can you please help